# how to search for a pattern in a file on other directory in python on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program where in I need to find a specific words in a file of another directory.
For ex: I am in `C:\python\ directory`, I want to search a pattern in a file which is located in D drive. `D:\Sample_file\file.txt`.
 I have many such files in the sample_file directory,where in which I need to 
 find specific words in that file.
 For example: In `D:\Sample_file\file.txt` I need to find `"hello world"` and 
 in `D:\Sample_file\file1.txt` I need to find "0 files not found" and in
 `D:\Sample_another\file3.txt` I need to find "oh my god!!" 
 how do I do it.

I have tried os.relpath but couldn't achieve the desired result

```
import os
paths = 'D:/'

def dir_list_folder(paths):
    for folderName in os.listdir(paths):     
       if (folderName.find('.') == -1):
           folderPath = os.path.join(paths,folderName );
           dir_list_folder(folderPath);
       else:
           print ('Files is :'+ folderName );
```

I expect to if it matches a pattern it should return `true`,else `false`

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of `for` loop that you're looking for. It is expected that `files` is a list of full paths to your files.

```
patterns = ['hello world', '0 files found']


for fileName in files:
    with open(fileName) as f:
        allLines = {x.strip() for x in f.readlines()}
    for pattern in patterns:
        if pattern in allLines:
            print('`%s` detected in %s' % (pattern, fileName))
            # then you can return True
        # and here False
```

Not 100% sure that this is the best approach, but I hope it helps you.